# Edit popup's light-box doesn't cover all of the behind content

Tags: bug, design

When I view stackoverflow on half screen width (ie <kbd>win</kbd> + <kbd>right</kbd>) or smaller, and click 'edit(1)' on a question, I have to scroll horizontally to see the remainder of the edit box. However, as shown below, the light box doesn't cover all the background content:

[image: Screenshot of edit popup and light-box]